# Calcular o produto cartesiano em Python, porém com condição para os elementos

Tags: python, matemática

Estou escrevendo uma função em python para retornar o produto cartesiano entre duas listas. Porém é preciso que o primeiro elemento do produto divida o segundo (satisfaça essa condição)
Exemplo:

```
Conjunto X: [2,3,4,6,8]
Conjunto Y: [2,3,4,6,8]
Resultado esperado: (2,2) (2,4) (2,8) (3,3) (3,6) (4,4) (4,8)
```

O que fiz:

```
conjunto_X = [[2,3,4,6,8],[2,3,4,6,8]]

def produto_cartesiano(conj_Inicial):
    resultado = [[]]
    for elementos in conj_Inicial:
        resultado = [a+[b] for a in resultado for b in elementos]
    return resultado

minhaLista = produto_cartesiano(conjunto_X)
print(minhaLista)
```

Saída dessa função:

```
[[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 8], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 6], [3, 8], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 6], [4, 8], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 6], [6, 8], [8, 2], [8, 3], [8, 4], [8, 6], [8, 8]]
```

Minha dúvida final é: Como inserir um if para só retornar (a,b) se (a % b == 0)?

Answer (score 1):

É, como deve imaginar, literalmente adicionar um `if` com a condição desejada.

```py
import itertools

A = [2,3,4,6,8]
B = [2,3,4,6,8]

# Aqui cartesian é o equivalente ao seu resultado, porém usando funções nativas do Python
cartesian = itertools.product(A, B)
result = [(a, b) for a, b in cartesian  if b % a == 0]

print(result)
# [(2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (3, 3), (3, 6), (4, 4), (4, 8), (6, 6), (8, 8)]
```

O resultado em si difere do seu esperado, mas porque o seu esperado não condiz com a regra que comentou, visto que os pares (6, 6) e (8, 8) satisfazem a condição e você não colocou que os esperava no resultado.

Também é importante salientar que a condição "*primeiro elemento do produto divida o segundo*" é representada por `b % a`, não `a % b`.